# True or False: If a series converges, then so does the series formed by the product of each member of it's power set

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}_{>0},\ $ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}:$ let $P(X_n)$ be the power set of $X_n = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} $ and then let $f_n:I_n\to P(X_n)$ be a bijection for some index set $I_n$ of $P(X_n).$

Proposition:

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ converges, then so does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i\in I_n} \left( \prod_{x_j\in f_n(i)} x_j \right).$

Hopefully this notation makes sense.

Is the proposition true? And what about if we let $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R},\ $ i.e. we allow  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ to be conditionally convergent also?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i\in I_n} \left( \prod_{x_j\in f_n(i)} x_j \right) =
1 + \sum_{k=1}^n x_k + \sum_{1 \le k < l \le n} x_k x_l + \cdots + \prod_{j=1}^n x_j \\
 = (1 + x_1)(1+x_2) \cdots (1+x_n) \, ,
$$
so your question is equivalent to asking if the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ implies that of the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x_n)$.

And that is indeed true if all $x_n \ge 0$:
$$
 \prod_{n=1}^{N} (1+x_n) \le \exp \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n\right) \, .
$$
The sequence on the right is convergent and therefore bounded, so that the sequence on the left is increasing and bounded above.

Actually in this case the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ is *equivalent* to the convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x_n)$ to a non-zero value. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product for more information.

For the case of a conditional convergent series, see for example [Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ converges conditionally or diverges to 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784877/42969).

Comment: Not sure why your answer got downvoted…